Units for electrical conductivity
I note from Wikipedia that electrical resistivity and conductivity are reciprocals of each other, and that the unit for electrical resistivity is the ohm-metre (Ω⋅m), while the unit for conductivity is siemens-per-metre (S⋅m$^{-1}$). Given that siemens is the reciprocal of ohm, would it be acceptable to use Ω$^{-1}$⋅m$^{-1}$ for electrical conductivity, or is this not really used?

It is definitely ok. There is a "mho" unit, which is just ohm written in reverse, and the symbol is an upside down ohm symbol. It is really silly.

@naturallyInconsistent sounds like an answer to me

Per Bob D's admonition:
"It is definitely ok. There is a "mho" unit, which is just ohm written in reverse, and the symbol is an upside down ohm symbol. It is really silly."
-a P.S.E user.

One may add that it depends on the concrete field (and the region you live in) which way to write a unit is customary. One example I know of is the conductivity of water (which serves as a proxy for the electrolyte content), which is commonly given in µS/cm.

Wait, isn't that also an answer? You should note that my answer is not my answer, and consider @Bob D's comment.

Probably, as you were answerifying the comment, I guessed my addition would fit fine. (And my answer/comment felt a bit too weak for an entire additional answer).
